# Catch exit code of external program in c++

Tags: c++

I am running an external program with the command `execvp`, now I want to catch the exit code of the external program and if possible get the `PID` of it.

Is there anyway possible?(I know I can read `$?` in ubuntu and use `ps faxu` but these are dirty ways for that)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `exec*` functions does not return when the program has successfully run, so you can't get the return code via `execvp`.  However, if you use `fork`/`wait`, you could get the exit code from the status code in the `wait*` functions:

```
int status;
if (wait(&status) != -1) {   // similar for waitpid, wait4, etc.
    if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
        exit_code = WEXITSTATUS(status);
    } else {
        // handle other conditions, e.g. signals.
    }
} else {
    // wait failed.
}
```

You could check the example of in the man page of [wait(2)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/wait.html#tag_03_822_06).

Answer (score 1):

Try also `int a_number = std::system("/path/to/app")`

This sometimes can be used to return the value of an xmessage query.